# How to get time from db depending upon conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which the value are

```
             Table_hello
date                            col2
2012-01-31 23:01:01             a
2012-06-2  12:01:01             b
2012-06-3  20:01:01             c
```

Now i want to select date

1. in days if it is 3 days before or less
2. in hours if it is 24 hours before or less
3. in minutes if it is 60 minutes before or less
4. in seconds if it is 60 seconds before or less
5. in simple format if it is before 3days or more

OUTPUT

```
for row1 2012-01-31 23:01:01 
for row2 1 day ago 
for row3 1 hour ago
```

UPDATE
My sql query

```
  select case 
            when TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `date`,current_timestamp) <= 60 
            then concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `date`,current_timestamp), ' seconds')
            when TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `date`,current_timestamp) <= 3 
            then concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `date`,current_timestamp), ' days')end
            when TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `date`,current_timestamp) <= 60 
            then concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `date`,current_timestamp), ' hours')
            when TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `date`,current_timestamp) <= 60 
            then concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `date`,current_timestamp), ' minutes')

from table_hello
```

Only problem is i am unable to use break and default in sql like switch case in c++

Comment: Could you provide some sample output? Like in the example above are you looking for it to output 75 days, 24 minutes, 10 seconds as row values?  Also do you mean by "simple format"

Comment: Simple format is to display date as it is stored

Comment: Why would this be easy if stored as an int but not a datetime?  Mysql has built in functions to get time difference.  Also, have you considered doing this comparison at the application level rather than in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [timestampdiff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function for that and `CASE`:

```
select case 
        when TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `date`,current_timestamp) <= 60 
        then concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `date`,current_timestamp), ' seconds')
        when TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `date`,current_timestamp) <= 3 
        and TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `date`,current_timestamp) >= 1 
        ...
       end as time_diff 
from Table_hello
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `time`,current_timestamp) >= 3
```

Comment: Nice but using 5 cases will speed down my query or not

Comment: Maybe a little. Test it and see if it is a problem for you.

Comment: By the way how will i come to know that time_diff is storing time in day not in hour or second

Comment: You could use `concat` for that. See my udpdate.

Comment: I fI understood you correctly then you want no all records from your table. Then use a `where` clause to restrict it. See my update. Is that what you want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12075/discussion-between-somebody-is-in-trouble-and-juergen-d)

Comment: You can add an `and` to your `when`case like this: `when TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date,current_timestamp) <= 3 
and TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date,current_timestamp) >= 1`